# How do pass data to a shared variable in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I have a kernel which passes 3 arrays, the first array d_A1 has no data and is used only to write back data, the other two arrays d_D1 and d_ST1 have data.

The size of the first array is:

```
d_A1[13000000]
```

The size of the second array is:

```
d_D1[421]
```

The size of the third array is:

```
d_ST1[21]
```

`N` is 13000000

```
TestArray<<<n_blocks, block_size>>>(d_A1,N, d_D1, d_ST1);
```

Now I want only pass the data of d_D1[421] and d_ST1[21] to shared arrays so I created the shared arrays as:

```
__global__ void TestArray(int* A1, unsigned int N,  int* D1, unsigned int* ST1)
{

   unsigned int __align__(16) tid = threadIdx.x;
   unsigned int __align__(16) idx = __umul24(blockDim.x, blockIdx.x) + threadIdx.x;  
   __shared__ unsigned int __align__(16) s_D1[441];  //Shared array for d_D1
   __shared__ unsigned int __align__(16) s_ST1[21];  //Shared array for d_ST1

   if (idx < N)   //13000000

   {
```

Q. How do I pass the data of d_D1[441] and d_ST1[21] to s_D1[441] and s_ST1[21]?
I tried:

```
      while (idx < 441)

        s_D1[tid] = d_D1[idx] 

      __syncthreads(); 


      while (idx < 21)

        s_ST1[tid] = d_ST1[idx] 


      __syncthreads();
```

but the computer freezes and I have to restart it. 
I also tried one at the time,namely, only the fist 
while and then only the second while, with no luck.

If I use the global memory, namely, d_D1, d_ST1 everything works. 
So the question is: 
How do you pass data to a shared variable/array when the size of the array is not N?

```
   }   //End of kernel processing



}
```

Comment: What are the parameters you're passing for number of blocks and threads?  Also, shouldn't those be "if" statements and not "while" for the bounds checking?

Comment: blocks = N/448, threads=448, even with if got the some result

Comment: Hmmmm, can you post more of the kernel you are using.  Also, looking at it again, if you're loading different slices of d_D1, d_ST1 into shared memory, don't you want to check on tid and not idx in the while/if bounds checking (otherwise you'll only ever load the first 441/21 values)?

Comment: Well, the kernel is tool long to be paste here. About the check on tid, no, the right syntax is checking the idx, because the idx goes all the way from 0 to 13000000. Now I've changed it to:
if (idx < 21) d_ST1[tid] = ST1[idx] and using uprintf I checked d_ST1[0], but it returns 0 instead of the value of ST1[0]

Comment: I'm not following, if D1 and ST1 are only 421 and 21 bytes in length, then you want if(tid<21) d_ST1[tid]=ST1[tid].  If D1 and ST1, are much longer and you want a slice to go to each block, then you want if(tid<21) d_ST1[tid]=ST1[idx] where you may need and additional check on idx if the length of ST1 is not an exact multiple of the number of threads (448).

Answer (score 1):

Great, you're right, it has to be if (tid < 21) d_ST1[tid] = ST1[tid] since one block is enough for those two size. Thanks you very much indeed.
However, when do you use if (idx < n) d_st1[tid] = st1[idx]?

Comment: One case where you would use if (idx < n) d_st1[tid] = st1[idx] is when the length of st1 is n, n < 512, and blocks, threads are <<<M/n, M>>>.  The more likely pattern is for n to be large, so you'll want to split the data among blocks.  Check out Nvidia's matrix multiply for a good example.

Comment: Should it be <<<n/M, M>> like n/number of threads per blocks?

Comment: So, If I understood correctly I will use "if(idx < n) d_st1[tid] = st1[idx]" only if st1[n] and n could be any number > 512 (max threads in a block)